# Casting the returnedData from a stored procedure in Entity Framework to List<ViewModel>

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

Here is my `ViewModel`:

```
public class CarViewModel
{
    public string Registration { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public DateTime Year { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult GetAllCars()
  {
        CarRentalEntities entities = new CarRentalEntities();
        List<CarViewModel> carsViewModel = new List<CarViewModel>();
        var cars = entities.GetAllCars();    
        // Is it possible to convert cars to carsViewModel Collection and 
        //return it to the view ????????????????
        return View(carsViewModel); 
  }
```

Here is my SQL stored procedure which is called by Entity Framework

```
Create Procedure  GetAllCars
as
(
    Select 
       c.registration, m.model_name, c.colour, m.model_year
    from 
       Cars c 
    inner join 
       models m on c.model_id = m.model_id
)
```

In my Entity Framework code all I want to do is convert the collection returned by the stored procedure `GetAllCars` of type `System.Data.Entity.Core.Object.ObjectResults<GetAllCars_Result>` into collection of type 
`List<CarViewModel>`.

How can this be achieved? I couldn't find proper tutorial or articles.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult GetAllCars()
  {
        CarRentalEntities entities = new CarRentalEntities();
        var cars = entities.GetAllCars();    

        List<CarViewModel> carsViewModel = cars.Select(c=> new CarViewModel
        {
         Registration = c.Registration,
         // and so on
        }).ToList();

        return View(carsViewModel); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Linq select method to do the transform on the enumeration.

So list =

```
cars.Select(c=>new viewmodel()  { 
    //initialize params here
});
```